# azure DevOps pipeline create a container app AzureContainerApps@1 with YML configuration file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-apps

Hi I am trying to deploy a container app from a azure register with yaml configuration as described in this article [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-container-apps-v1?view=azure-pipelines#minimal---use-yaml-configuration-file-with-previously-published-image-for-container-app) , but I keep getting an error **ERROR: environmentId is required**

```
2024-01-31T22:48:25.6503621Z WARNING: Additional flags were passed along with --yaml. 
These flags will be ignored, and the configuration defined in the yaml will be used 
instead
2024-01-31T22:48:25.6539605Z ##[error]Error Code: [1]
2024-01-31T22:48:25.6592150Z ERROR: environmentId is required. This can be retrieved 
using the `az containerapp env show -g MyResourceGroup -n MyContainerappEnvironment -- 
query id` command. Please see https://aka.ms/azure-container-apps-yaml for a valid 
containerapps YAML spec.
2024-01-31T22:48:25.6593468Z ##[error]Error: Unable to create Azure Container App from 
YAML configuration file via 'az containerapp create' command.
```

I run the command  'az containerapp env show -g MyResourceGroup... to get the enviromentId but still not working ,

Pipeline task

```
steps:
 - task: AzureContainerApps@1
  displayName: 'Azure Container Apps Deploy'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'hub-devops'
    acrName: containerregistry
    acrUsername: containerregistry
    acrPassword: '*****'
    resourceGroup: 'container-app'
    yamlConfigPath:'$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ContainerAppConfig.yml'
    disableTelemetry: false
```

config.yml file

```
properties:
managedEnvironmentId: /subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/container-app/providers/Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/***
configuration:
ingress:
  external: true
  allowInsecure: false
  targetPort: 80
template:
containers:
  - image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/containerapp:latest
    name: containerapp
```

Released task  using Azure Container Apps Deploy

[image: Task Azure Container Apps Deploy]

same error from the CLI

[image: AZ CLI]

I found other articles that refer to enviromentId instead of managedEnvironmentId

```
environmentId: "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/demokube"
```

I have tried with both properties, still not working.

so my question is what's the correct property and format to pass the **environmentId**

I can create the container app fine without passing the config.yml

thanks for your help

Comment: Does this documentation answer your question? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/azure-resource-manager-api-spec?tabs=yaml#container-app-examples ?

Comment: thanks @ScottRichards I did try that as well , still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Test the same YAML sample in my Pipeline and I noticed that the format of the YAML sample should be incorrect.

You are ignoring the indentation of each line in your YAML file.

The managedEnvironmentId has the same value as the environmentId. You don't need to add additional environmentId  parameters in the YAML file.

You can try to use the following YAML sample:

```
properties:
  managedEnvironmentId: /subscriptions/{SubId}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupID}/providers/Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/MyContainerappEnvironment
  configuration:
    ingress:
      external: true
      allowInsecure: false
      targetPort: 80
  template:
    containers:
      - image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/containerapps-helloworld:latest
        name: containerapp
```

You can get the managedEnvironmentId via the Azure CLI command:

```
az containerapp env show -g MyResourceGroup -n MyContainerappEnvironment --query id
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replay , I tried your YAML sample same issued , I am not sure if the YAML sample is getting pickup by the task , I am using  the Azure Container Apps Deploy task in the released pipeline

Comment: Added the release task screenshot to the original post . Did some more testing,  I created the container app by omitting the config.yaml file, it works fine , then added the file again with my setting, run the pipeline , no errors  but the container app is missing all the setting from the config file. any ideas ?

Comment: Do you mean that the pipeline can run successfully now with the yaml file? The error: ERROR: environmentId is required. has disappeared. And now the issue has changed to the settings are not shown?

Comment: yes but only after creating the app container without the config.yaml

Comment: If you use config.yaml, it still shows error? From the description in the question, can you confirm if the yaml file name is correct in your release pipeline and the source yaml file?

Comment: no errors because the container app is created, yes filename are the same , this is the log , 2024-02-01T10:07:20.0610651Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" containerapp update -n project-reportingdev -g srmdev-container-services --yaml D:\a\r1\a/_POCProjectReporting/Server/SRM.Microservice.Configuration/ContainerAppConfig/ContainerAppConfig.yaml"

Comment: is the file needs to be config.yaml or config.yml ?

Comment: ok more testing I did change the file name to an incorrect file and I got an error 'ERROR: D:\a\r1\a/_POCProjectReporting/Server/SRM.Microservice.Configuration/ContainerAppConfig/Config.yaml does not exist' , change the name back to the correct file no errors but the container app still missing all the setting from the config file

Comment: added a new screenshot getting the same error from Azure CLI .

Comment: @HernandoZ Can you try to use the Azure CLI: `az containerapp env create -n < environment name > -g < resource group >` to create  a new container app env and get the new managedEnvironmentId to set the yaml file for testing?

Comment: Hi Kevin , I giving up I can't get it to work , I decided to use bicep files for the container config. Thanks.